# Wine not working in 0.4 Loki

Tags: release-loki, wine

I installed wine, but the best I get is a blank screen for `wine notepad`.[image: No other application opens]
Wine itself does not start. It just shows an icon in the dock but no window opens. I initially installed using a binary, but seeing this problem, I uninstalled it and reinstalled using `apt-get`. However, after reinstallation, nothing changed. The problem remained. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, i have no problem and it works perfectly.

For info: i had installed `wine wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64` packages

You can also check witch packages u have installed using `apt list --installed`

[image: wine]